# What is Response.ListResponse?

Tags: java, spring

I am studying AxBoot for the first time. However, we do not understand where Responses.ListResponse is used in Code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
public Responses.ListResponse list(RequestParams<User> requestParams) {
    List<User> users = userService.get(requestParams);
    return Responses.ListResponse.of(users);
}
```

Is it object type? 
What does Of mean in Responses.ListResponse.Of? Help Me...

Comment: for more information on `ListResponse` you can have a look at [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/uddi/client/structures/response/ListResponse.html)

Comment: please add more details.e.g. where could we get this api. Also, at least share the package path of `Responses` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code search tool(sourcegraph) to check the class definition.

FYI: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/axboot/ax-boot-framework/-/blob/ax-boot-core/src/main/java/com/chequer/axboot/core/api/response/Responses.java?utm_source=share#L25

And more 'Response.ListResponse.of' usage, please check [lombok RequiredArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor).